# Conversion of java script to vb script

Tags: javascript, vbscript

I have tried as much as possible to change the code from javascript to vbscript... Can you help me if there is any error while changing..

```
     <script  language='vbscript' type='text/vbscript'>

Dim myVar = "";

function auto(data) 
Dim path = '<%=session.getAttribute("PATH")%>' ;
   Dim DocId = '<%=session.getAttribute("REQDOCUMENTID")%>' ;
   Dim extension = '<%=session.getAttribute("FILEEXTN")%>' ;
   Dim userId = '<%=session.getAttribute("REQUSERID")%>' ;
   Dim apolloenv = '<%=session.getAttribute("REQAPOLLOENV")%>' ;

   if(extension != '') Then
          Dim ext = LCase(extension);
          Dim fso  = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
          if (fso.FolderExists(path)) Then                                   
                 path = path & DocId & "." & ext;
                 document.ViewONE.save(path);
                 myVar=window.setInterval(Call checkFile(path,ext),1000);      
          End If
          if(DocId <> 'null' AND apolloenv <> 'null' AND userId <> 'null') Then
                 getNote(DocId,apolloenv,userId,"autolaunch executed");
          End If   
   End If
 End Function

    function checkFile(path,ext)

   set fso  = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
   if(fso.FileExists(path)) Then
          Call openfile(ext, path);
          window.clearInterval(myVar);
End If
End Function




function openfile(ext, path) 
   if(ext == 'docx' || ext == 'doc'|| ext == 'docm') Then
          Dim oApplication = CreateObject("Word.Application");
          oApplication.Visible = true;
          oApplication.Documents.Open(path, false, 0);
   ElseIf (ext == 'xls'||ext == 'xlsx' ||ext == 'xlsm' ||ext == 'xlsb' ||ext == 'xltx' ||ext == 'xltm') Then
          Dim objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application");
          objExcel.Visible = true;
          objExcel.Workbooks.Open(path, false, 0); 
   ElseIf  (ext == 'pptx'|| ext == 'ppt' || ext == 'pptm') Then
          Dim objPPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application");
          objPPT.Visible = true;
          objPPT.Presentations.Open(path, false, 0); 
   ElseIf (ext == 'msg' || ext == 'eml') Then
          WSH = CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
          WSH.run("file://"+path, 1);
   ElseIf (ext == 'jpg' || ext == 'tif' || ext == 'png' || ext == 'bmp' || ext == 'mdi' || ext == 'gif') Then
          imageWSH = CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
          imageWSH.run("file://"+path, 1);
   ElseIf (ext == 'txt') Then
          txtwshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
          txtwshShell.run("file://"+path, 1);
   ElseIf (ext == 'pdf') Then
          wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
          wshShell.run("file://"+path, 1);
   Else
       msgbox "Please use the right click AutoLaunch option available in Apollo as this document type will not be supported by daejaviewer's AutoLaunch."
End If       
End Function
```

Am not sure about getNote, Document, session.attribute function which is there in javascript to change it to vbscript

Comment: why do you write "java script" but "vbscript" (without space). Further you tagged this question with java.Java has nothing todo with javascript. only the first 4 letters are the same.like in car and carpet.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript you can declare and initialize a variable in one statement:

```
var x = "whatever";
```

In VBScript you need a Dim and an assignment:

```
Dim x : x = "whatever"
```

In Javascript statements are terminated by ";"; VBScript does not use statement terminators -

```
window.clearInterval(myVar);
```

should throw a syntax error. Additional example:

```
oApplication.Documents.Open(path, false, 0);
==>
oApplication.Documents.Open path, false, 0
```

Javascript needs param list () all over the place; VBScript does not use param list () when calling a (Sub/Function/Method as a) Sub.

```
window.clearInterval myVar
```

is VBScript for the above call.

Work thru the docs for [VBScript operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9da4s2eh%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) to make lines like

```
if(ext == 'docx' || ext == 'doc'|| ext == 'docm') Then
```

decent.

The string literal delimiter is " in VBScript, not ' (or ") as in Javascript. To check for Null (as opposed to a string literal "null") you need the [IsNull()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zbchw6hz%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) function. So

```
DocId <> 'null'
```

is a double blunder.

VBScript needs `Set` when assigning an object to a variable:

```
Dim oApplication = CreateObject("Word.Application");
==>
Dim oApplication : Set oApplication = CreateObject("Word.Application")
```

There may be more mistakes; I advice you to correct the indicated problems and to post a better revision to get help on the remaining errors.

Comment: i had changed the code according to the changes mentioned to be done. But the code doesn't work yet